# Why didn't Jeetu and Yogi just lodge an FIR against the hacker?

Tags: plot-explanation, tvf-pitchers

In the Indian web-series [TVF Pitchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TVF_Pitchers), Why didn't Jeetu and Yogi just lodge an FIR against the hacker dungeon_master after he copied their idea?

He already broke their Hard-drive which consisted of Yogi's skype chats. He could have easily handled the case.

<sub>Note : A First Information Report (FIR) is a written document prepared by police organizations in Bangladesh, India, and Pakistan when they receive about the commission of a cognizable offence.[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Information_Report)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is in the words of Ankit Bhardwaj in the meeting:

> You can copyright a product not an idea.

I am not a legal person but as per show point of view this was the reason.

Its even a fact that [Copyrights protect expression and patents protects inventions, and neither protect ideas](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=can%20idea%20be%20copyrighted). So there was no case.

Even if they do lodge FIR, they need to proof themselves right in court and that's not easy at all and even against a hacker who hold sex chats of Yogi and hold extra ordinary hacking abilities. And even Jitu destroyed their property and they can lodge cross case against them. And a court case takes years and lot of money to clear and for jobless people it will be too tough to handle.